# React MUI removes 'content' from CSS pseudo element

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am creating a React MUI Box, and styling it as follows

```
<Box
  id='my-box'
  sx={{
    '&::before': {
      content: 'Yay! ',
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
  }}
>Life is beautiful</Box>
```

However, at runtime, the CSS property `content` is removed, and only `background-color` is kept. If I go to the browser dev tools and manually type in `content: 'Yay! '`, then it will appear as it should.

To show you in detail:

1. Here is a screenshot of my code:

[image]

2. Here is what the browser incorrectly shows:

[image]

3. Upon inspecting the element via dev tools, this is what I see (notice that `content` is missing):

[image]

4. So I manually added `content` via dev tools, resulting in this:

[image]

5. And doing step 4 above, results in this, as expected:

[image]

So how do I make sure the CSS property `content` is not removed at runtime? And why does this happen in the first place?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double-quote ***and*** single-quote the `content` prop within `sx`. For example:

```
<Box
  id="my-box"
  sx={{
    "&::before": {
      content: "'Yay! '",
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  }}
>
  Life is beautiful
</Box>
```

The result should be:

[image: image of working example]

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-golick-zl6drq?file=/demo.tsx:119-299

*(Usually doing it the way you provided should have produced the error message: `Error: You seem to be using a value for 'content' without quotes, try replacing it with content: '"Yay! "'`.)*

Comment: I love you man, the brotherly kinda love! You saved me, been stuck on this for hours! Thank you. (And BTW, I did not get an error!).